# This survey ________ your health as well as that of your family

Tags: exam-questions

> This survey **is concerning**  your health as well as that of your family.

This is a sentence improvement question asked in my exam.

I was given four options to choose from :

(A) concerns with

(B) is concerned with

(C) concerns to

(D) no improvement

Which is the correct / appropriate answer here ?

I can rule out option C but I am confused between option A, B and D.

Answer (score 1):

Option D is incorrect since the sentence loses its verb. Concern is a transitive verb, so it needs an object; therefore, option A is also omitted. The correct one is B. "Concerned with something/somebody" is an expression meaning "related to or about something/somebody."

Answer (score 0):

Option D is incomplete as it lacks an object to qualify the word no improvement.

Option A is also incomplete because it also lack an object

I would go for Option B.